# ElasticSearch on Cassandra data vs moving Cassandra data to ElasticSearch for Indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra

I'm new to ElasticSearch and am trying to figure out what is the most optimal way to index 1 Terabyte of data in Cassandra.

Two options that I understand right now are:

1. Move data periodically to ElasticSearch using the Cassandra-River plugin and then run index on the data.
   Advantage: Search queries create no impact on Cassandra load
   Disadvantage: Have to sync the data periodically
2. Without moving the data run ElasticSearch on Cassandra to index the data (not sure how will this be done).
   Advantage: Data always in sync
   Disadvantage: Impacts Cassandra performance ?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054954/elasticsearch-vs-cassandra-vs-elasticsearch-with-cassandra/27072018#27072018

Answer (score 0):

Prehaps in the context of ElasticSearch 1.4 and above.. just using ElasticSearch as a datastore and search engine might be simpler and elegant option.
Add more nodes to scale.