# Cassandra - Do we have any thing similar to MySQL %like%?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I have a table and data as shown below, I want to query records containing owner. Any help please ?

```
select name from team where blob  like %owner%

CREATE TABLE ipl.team(
    name text,
    captain text,
    blob text,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, captain)
) 

  name  |  captain | blob
------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------
   KKR |  SRK      | {'owner': 'ABC', 'win': '10'}
   DD  |  ME       | {'owner': 'XYZ', 'win': '8'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm hoping you are not really storing JSON in a text field (it's a bit of a waste), I will try to answer.

In short, no, it does not. It is a key/value store, although with a more complicated storage model than, for example, Riak.

If you want to do something like that, you should implement a text search engine like elastic search, which is a separate topic altogether. You might want to check this quesiton: [Elasticsearch vs Cassandra vs Elasticsearch with Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054954/elasticsearch-vs-cassandra-vs-elasticsearch-with-cassandra)