# Can Lucene Be used to store continuous streams of data and act as datastore for Analytics.!

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene, cassandra, analytics

Can Apache lucene be used as a database , I mean to say that, I have performed POC and have seen that it can index data very fast and searching is also very fast in Lucene.

Suppose,my problem statement is: I have a continuous incoming streams of data, which I want to store in a datastore, and query from that store to get real time analytics.What I have done is I buffere the data and create lucene indexes out of the buffered data (buffered data interval is say, 2-5 seconds) , and then use that index to perform the read operations on the data.

Will Lucene work properly for Analytics if I keep on indexing data , say 5 MB every second (69 GB a day) on top of exisitng data, and concurrently perform reads on the indexed data..???
I am trying cassandra also to test this scenario but I know Lucene has good Search speed and indexes data pretty fast..tooo. So can I use it as a database for incomming traffic and then query on that incomming traffic to fetch data for reports.???

Kindly let me know of the available alternative technologies as well, If any, in the market. (best if it is open source)

Thanks in advance..
cheerss.!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch vs Cassandra vs Elasticsearch with Cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054954/elasticsearch-vs-cassandra-vs-elasticsearch-with-cassandra)

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23, thank you for addressing my quesiton. My question however revolved around real time analytics and how Lucene can help me capture incomming data traffic (to create indexes) and query the historic and present indexed data on top of that .. real time or near real time.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer, if anyone can guide wrt the above problem statement. :)