# searching Mysql table with Elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, replication

Lets say I have the following "expenses" MySQL Table:

| id | amount | vendor | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | google | foo |
| 2 | 450 | GitHub | bar |
| 3 | 22 | GitLab | fizz |
| 4 | 75 | AWS | buzz |

I'm building an API that should return expenses based on partial "vendor" or "tag" filters, so vendor="Git" should return records 2&3, and tag="zz" should return records 3&4.
I was thinking of utilizing elasticsearch capabilities, but I'm not sure the correct way..
most articles I read suggest replicating the table records (using logstash pipe or other methods) to elastic index.

So my API doesn't even query the DB and return an array of documents directly from ES?

Is this considered good practice? replicating the whole table to elastic?
What about table relations... What If I want to filter by nested table relation?...

Comment: There is no way around it. To use elasticsearch capabilities you need to host the data in elasticsearch.
Yes they are some limitation such as no relationships in Elasticsearch.

From your example I believe you could do something with the fuzzy match in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my API doesn't even query the DB and return an array of documents
> directly from ES?

Yes, As you are doing query to elasticsearch, you will get result only from Elasticsearch. Another way is, just get id from Elasticsearch and use id to retrive documeents from MySQL, but this might impact response time.

> Is this considered good practice? replicating the whole table to
> elastic? What about table relations... What If I want to filter by
> nested table relation?...

It is not about good practice or bad practice, it is all about what type of functionality and use case you want to implement and based on that technology stack can be used and data can be duplicated. There is lots of company using Elasticsearch as `secondary` data source where they have duplicated data just because there usecase is best fit with Elasticsearh or other NoSQL db.

Elasticsearch is NoSQL DB and it is not mantain any relationship between data. Hence, you need to denormalize your data before indexing to the Elasticsearch. You can read [this](https://spoon-elastic.com/all-elastic-search-post/simple-elastic-usage/denormalize-index-elasticsearch/) article for more about denormalizetion and why it is required.

ElasticSearch provide [Nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and [Join](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) data type for parent child relationship but both have some limitation and performance impact.

Below is what they have mentioned for `join` field type:

> The join field shouldn’t be used like joins in a relation database. In
> Elasticsearch the key to good performance is to de-normalize your data
> into documents. Each join field, `has_child` or `has_parent` query adds a
> significant tax to your query performance. It can also trigger global
> ordinals to be built.

Below is what they have mentioned for `nested` field type:

> When ingesting key-value pairs with a large, arbitrary set of keys,
> you might consider modeling each key-value pair as its own nested
> document with `key` and `value` fields. Instead, consider using the
> `flattened` data type, which maps an entire object as a single field and
> allows for simple searches over its contents. Nested documents and
> queries are typically expensive, so using the `flattened` data type for
> this use case is a better option.

> most articles I read suggest replicating the table records (using
> logstash pipe or other methods) to elastic index.

Yes, You can use `logstash` or any language client like `java`, `python` etc, to sync data from DB to Elasticsearch. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37309866/5489276) SO answer for more information on this.

**Your Search Requirements**

If you go ahead with Elasticsearch then you can use [N-Gram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) or [Regex Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) and achieve your search requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try TiDB: https://medium.com/@shenli3514/simplify-relational-database-elasticsearch-architecture-with-tidb-c19c330b7f30

If you want to scale your MySQL and have fast filtering and aggregating, TiDB could simplify the architecture and reduce development work.